# how update two tables from Edit View ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to update data from two tables; `products` and `inventory`. The main key of the table `products` is `cod_prod`, which is the barcode of a product. This is the relationship with the `products` table and the other. The update is carried out for all the fields, but in the database administrator, the `cod_prod` field in the `inventory` table is not updated, it only becomes `null`, in the `products` table the update is carried out, the `reg_date` field, which is a field in the `inventory` table is also updated. Only the `cod_prod` field on the `inventory` table is not updated and I don't know why.

ViewModel:

```
public class products
{

   [Display(Name = "Name")]
   public string name { get; set; }

   [Key]
   [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
   public string cod_prod { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Register Date")]
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? reg_date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult prodEdit(int id)
{
    using (inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
    {
        var u = dc.products.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (u != null)
        {
            var pm = new products
            {
                name = u.name,
                cod_prod = u.cod_prod,
                reg_date = u.reg_date
            };

            var b = dc.inventory.Where(x => x.cod_prod == pm.cod_prod).FirstOrDefault();

            u.cod_prod = b.cod_prod;

            return View(u);
        }

        return Content("Invalid Request");

    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult prodEdit(products prod)
{
    using (inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
    {

        var u = dc.products.Where(a => a.id == prod.id).FirstOrDefault();

        var b = dc.inventory.Where(x => x.cod_prod == prod.cod_prod).FirstOrDefault();

        inventory bod = new inventory()
        {
            cod_prod = prod.cod_prod,
            reg_date = prod.reg_date
        };

        
        dc.inventory.Remove(b);
        dc.inventory.Add(bod);
        dc.products.Remove(u);
        dc.products.Add(prod);
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("prodList", "products");

    }
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Model for `products`:

```
public partial class products
{

   [Display(Name = "Name")]
   public string name { get; set; }

   [Key]
   [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
   public string cod_prod { get; set; }
}
```

Model for `inventory`:

```
public partial class inventory
{
   [Key]
   [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
   public string cod_prod { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Register Date")]
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? reg_date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show your Models please.

Comment: I updated the question with the models for both tables. Again, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `POST` action and see whether `cod_prod` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have one to one relation between Products and Inventory tables, your models will look like this in EF:

Products model

```
public class Products
{

   [Display(Name = "Name")]
   public string name { get; set; }

   [Key]
   [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
   public string cod_prod { get; set; }

   public virtual Inventory Inventory {get;set;}
}
```

Inventory model

```
public class Inventory
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Products")]
   [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
   public string cod_prod { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Register Date")]
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? reg_date { get; set; }

   public virtual Products Products {get;set;}
}
```

Once relation is configured, you can simply do this in the POST method to update product and inventory:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult prodEdit(Products prod)
{
    using (inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
    {

        var product = dc.products.Where(a => a.id == prod.id).FirstOrDefault();

        var inventory = product.Inventory;

        inventory.cod_prod = prod.cod_prod;
        inventory.reg_date = prod.reg_date;
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("prodList", "products");

    }
}
```

You can read more about how to configure EF relation [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really didn't know that I could do the update this way. The solution I posted was the only way I could find to solve the problem, but with this solution you can tell that it is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If the same thing happens to someone, this is what I wrote to resolve it, the `controller` has two `post` methods, the first removes the fields that were changed, save data base and send the `products` and `inventory` objects to the second method, there, adds the new data of the models and save. I had to do this way because the removal of the PK on the `products` table causes the `null` thing.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult prodEdit(products prod)
    {
        using(inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
        {
            var u = dc.products.Where(a => a.id == prod.id).FirstOrDefault();

            if(u != null)
            {
                var pm = new products
                {
                    prod_name = prod.prod_name,
                    cod_prod = prod.cod_prod,
                    fecha_ingreso = prod.fecha_ingreso
                };

                var b = dc.bodega.Where(x => x.cod_prod == u.cod_prod).FirstOrDefault();
                
                if (b != null)
                {

                    inventory inv = new inventory()
                    {
                        reg_date = pm.fecha_ingreso,
                        cod_prod = pm.codigo_prod
                    };



                    if (inv.cod_prod != null)
                    {
                        dc.inventory.Remove(b);
                        dc.products.Remove(u);

                        dc.SaveChanges();

                        prodEdit2(prod, bod);
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("prodList", "products");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult prodEdit2(products p, inventory i)
    {
        using (inventarioEntitiesDBA dc = new inventarioEntitiesDBA())
        {
            dc.products.Add(p);
            dc.inventory.Add(i);

            dc.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("prodList", "products");
        }
    }
```